# Lots of small mysql table or one big table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, structure

I have a forum where i have properties like - >
`follow`,`voteup`,`votedown`,`report`,`favorite`,`view` etc for each thread,answers,comments.

Which approach will be performance wise faster and better ?
I am expecting billions of `favorite`,`views` etc....just like `youtube`

### **Approach One**

Make one big table `counter`

`counter_id | user_id | object_id | object_type | property`

where `object_type` = `thread`,`comment`,`answer` with their respective `id` from tables `threads`,`comments`,`answers`

and `property` = `follow`,`voteup`,`votedown`,`report` etc

### **Approach Two**

Make individual tables of `follow`,`views`,`report` etc

- `views`

  `view_id | user_id | object_id | object_type`
- `follows`

  `follow_id | user_id | object_id | object_type`

Comment: Will the real slim shady stand up

Comment: Separate your tables.  Doing everything under one giant table is neither efficient, maintainable, nor ideal.

Comment: I agree, separate the tables.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard its "Will the real slim shady `please` stand up"

Comment: Since i am having a `1-to-1 relationship` wouldnt it be better to `denormalize` my table ?  @Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: @SlimShady I'm not sure what you mean by `denormalize`, but I'm pretty sure the answer is no.

Comment: `denormalize = combine lots of tables into one` @Jean-FrançoisSavard

Comment: @SlimShady Go easy on the code tags.  They're there for code, not key words.

Comment: @SlimShady Then the answer is no. I see no point in creating a big table, it will simply be less clear on how to find specific data.

Comment: @SlimShady I'm very calm. And I just answered your question... Others were taking the **** about your use of code tags. I thought I'd be more polite and give you some friendly advice.  Since you're new to asking questions here may I politely recommend http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html It even cover's the subject of getting angry with others on forums.

Comment: oh i m really sorry @couling i mistaken you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single answer to this, its quite subjective.

Most commonly it's best to consider the use cases for your design.  Think carefully about what these fields will be used for before you add them to any table.  And don't think that you have to add a numeric primary key ("ID") to every table.  A table for tracking follows is just fine with only the fields `user id | object id | object type`  and all three fields contained in the primary key.

Its unlikely your code ever will be used with such performance constraints as youtube or even stack overflow.  If it is you will most likely have remodelled the database by then.

However for the sake of the exercise consider where and how data is to be used...

I would have separate tables as follows

**Follow**
User feeds, probably needs its own table as most commonly it gets hit from anywhere (a bit like a global inbox).  The follow should also have some flag or timestamp to show changes so that its very easy to evaluate when changes have occurred since the last time the user was online.......

This is because a user needs to see what they've followed as some sort of feed and other's need to see how many people have followed.  But other's don't need to see who else has followed.

**Vote up, Vote down**
That's just vote and a +- flag.  Do denormalize this... That is store BOTH a user's individual votes in a table and store a count of votes against object on a field on the object's table.  That way you only ever check a single user's vote (they're own) for a page view.  The counts are retrieved from the same row containing the content.

Again.  A user needs to see what they've up/down voted.  You need to check they're not voting twice.  What matters is the final count.  So checking an object with a million up votes should not have to hit a million rows - Just one.

*Pro tip:*  Some database engines perform badly if you constantly update rows with large content.  So consider a "meta-data" table for all objects. Which stores counts such as this.  This leaves the meta data free to update frequently even if the content doesn't.

**Favorite**
Own table again. `user id | object id | object type`. If you want to display number of favourites to the public then keep a count of this against the object, don't do a `select count(*)` every page view.

**View**
Why even store this?  Keep a count against the object.  If you're going to store a history then make sure you put a timestamp against it and purge it regularly.   You don't need to store what a user was looking at six months ago.

---

As a general observation all of these are separate tables with the exception of up and down votes.

You should denormalize the counts to reduce the quantity of data your server needs to access to determine a page view.  Most commonly a page view should be the fastest thing.  Any form of update can be a little slower.

---

Where I mention for *favourites* and others that they don't need an additional primary key field.  What I mean is that they have a primary key, just not an additional field.  For example favourites could be:

```
CREATE TABLE favourites (
    user INT,
    object_type INT,
    object_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user, object_type, object_id)
)
```

There's simply no reason to have a `favorite_id` field.

Comment: Man but how I am gonna store view without any table?  If a user opens a page twice or thrice or even more times then the page view is simply gonna keep increasing for the object

Comment: Yes that is a legitimate use for it. You need to purge it though.  So keep the data for a week or two, but not longer.

Comment: Then if the same person visits page after a week or two then views will increase? @couling

Comment: This is where it's very important to think about what behaviour you want and then think about what the minimum amount of data you need to store this.

It's not uncommon for "views" to be session views so if a user comes back another time (with a new session cooky) then it registers a new view.  That way you only ever need to store views from active sessions.  Expired sessions get purged.  But if that's not what you want then you need to store more data to get what you want.

Comment: Database design is often taught poorly at school / college.  It focuses to heavily on thinking about how to represent what is and far to little on how you're going to use it.

Comment: And how can i have a table without `primary key AI` ? I wont be able to modify,delete the rows of that table !! @couling

Comment: You can have a compost primary key (eg: made up of user/object type/objectid). You don't need to add an extra numeric field, that just wastes data and doesn't help you.

Comment: Alright  got it ! But i still didnt get the `View` stuff!! A person may have seen thousands of pages and thus storing thousands of  `object_id` in session it quite a big problem @couling

Comment: It's got to be stored somewhere. You pick the location it's stored.  Storing against the session doesn't mean "in the session" it means keyed by the session instead of the user.  That gives you an easy way to purge the data as sessions expire.

Comment: oh ! do you mean that i store the `views` somewhere in `clients` computer and save the `location` in the `session` ? @couling

Comment: It's up to you.  I'd store them in the same database, unless you have a specific DB for storing sessions. But I'd have the table be `user_session_key | object_type | object_id`.  This is high volume data that you don't need to keep for eternity. So think about how you're going to get rid of it when it's done with.  And what do YOU think is the right time to be done with it.  Different sites use different strategies.

Comment: Ja, Danke! Junge! @couling

Answer (score 1):

Answer, Part 1:  Plan on redesigning as you go.

The best advice I can give you is to plan for change.  What you design for the first million will not work for 30 million.  The 30-million design will not survive to a billion.  Whatever you do after reading this thread may last you through 30K rows.

Why is this?  Well, partially because you will not be able to do it in a single machine.  Don't shard your database now, but keep in the back of your mind that you will need to shard it.  At that point, much of what worked on a single machine will either not work on multiple machines, or will be too slow to work.  So you will have to redesign.

Let me point out another aspect of 1 billion rows.  Think how fast you have to do INSERTs to grow a table to 1B rows in 1 year.  It's over 30 per second.  That's not bad, until you factor in the spikes you *will* get.

And what will happen when your second billion won't fit on the disk you have laid out?

Anyone who grows to a billion rows has to learn as he goes.  The textbooks don't go there; the manuals don't go there; only the salesmen go there, but they don't stick around after the check clears.  Look at YouTube (etc) -- almost nothing is "off the shelf".

And think of how many smart designers you will need to hire to get to 1 billion.

It is painful to add a column to a billion-row table, so (1) plan ahead, and (2) design a way to make changes without major outages.

Answer, Part 2:  Some tips

Here are some of my comments on the ideas bounced around, and some tips from someone who has dealt with a billion-row, sharded system (not YouTube, but something similar).

Normalize vs denormalize:  My motto:  "Normalize, but don't overnormalize."  You'll see what I mean after you have done some of it.

One table vs many:  Two tables with the essentially identical CREATE TABLEs should *usually* be a single table.  (Sharding, of course, violates that.)  OTOH, if you need thousands of `UPDATE...view_count = view_count + 1` per second it won't survive to a billion.  However, it might survive to a million; then plan for change.

Minimize the size of datatypes -- Using a MEDIUMINT instead of an INT for one column saves a gigabyte.

Do not paginate using OFFSET and LIMIT.  (I have a blog on a workaround.)

Batch INSERTs where possible.

Use InnoDB, you don't want to wait hours for a REPAIR to finish on a MyISAM table.

The simple task of getting a unique ID for the 'next' item can be a huge problem in a sharded system.  Wait until you are closer to needing sharding before redesigning that part.  Do not use UUIDs for a billion-row table; they *will* perform poorly.  So, don't even think about UUIDs now; you *will* have throw them away.

Long before you hit 1 billion, you will have nightmares about the one machine crashing.  Think about replication, HA, etc, early.  It is painful to set up such after you have big tables.

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination -- and various other blogs are linked from it.